# NSOperation finished

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperation running in a NSOperationQueue. The NSOperation downloads some data and parses it into NSDictionary. How do I know when the NSOperation has finished and get that dictionary?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `NSOperation`'s `- (void)setCompletionBlock:`:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Doing something...");
}];

[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Doing something once the operation has finished...");
}];

[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Much more detail [here](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html).

Comment: It is important to note that there is no guarantee (1) when and (2) on which thread the completion block is executed. The documentation goes into these issues into more detail. Of course, the completion block is executed after the operation finishes. What is uncertain is the exact moment (order) that it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

If the block of code that needs to know when the operation is finished is itself an NSOperation, then you can gracefully handle this by establishing a dependency between them:

```
[laterOp addDependency:downloadAndParseOp];
```

The laterOp will be executed only after downloadAndPareOp has finished.

In fact, I would encourage you to write your code so that this approach is possible.  One of the biggest strengths of NSOperations and NSOperationQueue is that it easily coordinates code execution.

Comment: The biggest problem with downloading is if you are using `NSURLSession` then your operation will be asynchronous. i.e. the operation will complete, and then sometime later, the download will complete. Workarounds: Make NSURLSession synchronous, or subclass NSOperation to only set `isFinished` after the download is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The usual thing to do is to have the NSOperation call a method on whatever object needs to know that the operation is complete. Or you could use NSNotificationCenter to allow various objects to listen for the update in a more decentralized manner. Or you could use KVO to listen on the NSOperation's `isFinished` property.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to initialize your NSOperation with a delegate. When the NSOperation has finished his job, he will call the delegate using one of the delegate's methods (declared through a protocol).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't think this would work since the operation is in a different thread, but let me try this.

Comment: No problem with the fact that you are on a different thread. Your message will get to your delegate.